# What does "on Sundays ring road supermarket" mean?

Tags: lyrics

This is a line from a Radiohead song "Fitter Happier":

> on Sundays ring road supermarket

What does it mean?

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you know what *on Sundays* means? *ring road*? *superrmarket*?

Comment: Note that song lyrics not only do not have to follow conventional grammar or  pronunciation, they do not have to *mean* anything. The songwriter could have chosen words that sound evocative, or which match a certain beat or rhyme pattern, or which are deliberately absurd and fanciful. There are countless websites devoted to interpreting song lyrics; you might get more meaningful answers at Lyreka, or Genius.com, or SongMeanings.com, or many others.

Comment: @AlanCarmack What I don't understand is why you write such an unhelpful comment.

Comment: Hayze, this is a learner's site and most the time we try to pinpoint/clarify what the learner is having difficulty with. If you go to a dentist with a complaint  the dentist will do the same. Learners are at many different levels: some don't know what a prepositional phrase is, some ask questions about Shakespeare. There's not much sense in giving answers until we get a better idea of exactly where the learner's difficulty lies.

Comment: Not sure what the confusion is here - it's a simple question, one of semantics rather than structure or definition. What does the line,as a whole, actually mean? Of course, it invites an answer that is imprecise, that invites interpretation. But I don't see a problem with that if it helps the OP, who is probably unaware that he is missing essential contextual data, to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fitter Happier is list.

Thom Yorke(writer) described it as "A list of 90's slogans" and "The most upsetting thing thing I've ever written"

It's certainly not meant to be grammatically correct.

I suspect that the meaning would be lost to non-British English speakers. Here's my interpretation.

I'm a similar age to Thom York, we grew up in the seventies and eighties when Sunday trading was illegal for most businesses. When the law changed in the nineties, England saw a huge growth in out-of-town shopping with many large shops opening on the outskirts of towns (on the ring-roads). Sundays changed for many people as a result and Sunday shopping became a normal and respectable thing to do.

Sunday's ring-road supermarket (my punctuation) is therefore somewhere that 'decent' people go to and something that should be done if the artist (with more than a hint of cynicism) is to become a better person.

That's my take on it anyway...

Comment: And this is total speculation, which is why questions about songs as a whole are usually closevoted. We still don't know *what* Hayze was having problems with. A legitimate answer does not have to resort to changing *on Sundays* to *on Sunday's*. Especially since there follows the line *Also on Sundays*.

Comment: When you quote someone or something you should give the  source.

Comment: Of course it's speculation (although I prefer interpretation) there's been no attempt to hide that. But that's rather the point. Poetry and lyrics use language to evoke an interpretation, a reaction. They may mean different things to different people and in different contexts. I'm always uneasy about the sometimes unseemly enthusiasm to close questions for being unclear - language is often unclear.